# How can a list of table's field names be queried from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, field

How can a plain text list of the field names of table be retrieved from PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/information-schema.html).[COLUMNS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/infoschema-columns.html), like this:

```
SELECT
    column_name,
    data_type,
    character_maximum_length,
    ordinal_position
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```

Better still, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is almost universally supported by all popular SQL databases, so this should work anywhere.

If you really want just dump plain text file recipe, you can execute this query using command line `psql` and save it as CSV or something like that.